# Definir la altura ajustable automáticamente al contenido de la celda en un iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument

Tags: itext

Me gustaría que las celdas del PdfDocument ajustaran su altura dinámicamente según la cantidad de texto.
Con la propiedad SetHeight se establece la altura de celda con un determinado valor. Actualmente lo calculo según el número de caracteres, pero no es una solución muy buena para todas las configuraciones de los diferentes equipos, ya que el escenario es cambiante por las fuentes de texto disponibles.
¿Existe alguna propiedad de PdfDocument o de Cell para controlar este aspecto? Lo ideal sería que el valor de la altura pudiera cambiar automáticamente para adaptarse a la cantidad de texto o a las dimensiones de cualquier otro objeto contenido.

Gracias

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado! Realmente era mucho más sencillo de lo pensaba.

Las celdas tienen un método setHeight para asignar una altura determinada. Cuando no se establece una altura con ese método entonces el comportamiento es justamente el que quería. La altura de la celda se adapta a la cantidad de texto contenido.